# Xen DomU: jfs support

Tags: xen, jfs

I have a domU that I plan to use the standard xen-kernel of my dom0 (Xen 4, Linux kernel 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64). On this domU I want to make all partitions jfs. (currently I am working in a testing domU with ext3 partitions)

In my dom0, I have no problem mounting jfs filesystems. However when I boot the domU with this kernel, jfs is not recognised as a filesystem type and cannot be mounted. When I boot the domU with a different kernel (the one that was generated during xen-create-image, 2.6.32-33-server) the jfs partition mounts correctly.

How can I correctly configure the system so that jfs is supported?

EDIT: I checked /proc/filesystems and jfs is listed on the dom0, but not on the domU, while using the same kernel.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, jfs is compiled as a module and is loaded in dom0 (for any of numerous reasons) but not domU. Perhaps manually insmod'ing jfs.ko in domU will resolve problem?

Comment: Is it possible that jfs.ko, is incompatible with the older xen kernel. When I try to load the module, it reports "insmod: error inserting 'jfs.ko': -1 Invalid module format". If so, where do I get the correct jfs.ko?